# The Compiler Warning shows up even when the import it shows as unused, is actually not being used in the class

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings, javac

I usually prefer keeping the code clean from all the Compiler warnings- be it unused import, unused variable, unused private methods, unnecessary suppress, unchecked, unnecessary cast, unnecessary condition (always be true or false), unannotated overridden methods  or reference to deprecated class/methods.

But this particular warning keeps showing up even when the import it shows as unused, is actually not being used in the class(at least not anymore). I need to know how to get that fixed.

I did try cleaning up the Project, Organizing the Imports, Building the project and also tried restarting the eclipse.

But what fixes the issue is when I delete the class and create the same class over again. That's really not a solution. There has to be quicker way to do that without having to do a re-work.

Any thoughts?

[image: SCREENSHOT OF THE CLASS FROM THE ECLIPSE IDE]

Comment: For some time I was confused by your language, stating that the compiler reports an import is unused and you stating it was really not used, so: what should be the conflict? Looking at the pictures it seems, however, the editor is out of sync wrt the warning marker. (What does the Problems view show?) If this situation persists even after building the project (is build automatically enabled??) then this might be a bug in Eclipse. If it happens reproducibly in the latest release version please consider filing a bug at Eclipse. BTW: Are you aware of Shift-Ctrl-O?

Comment: An Import at some point was being un-used in the class and is now removed. But somehow the compiler kept reporting the unused warning 'over' another import which was actually being used in the class. So the conflict here was it was showing the warning incorrectly. I didn't have Build Automatically enabled. I did Build the project manually, cleaned it but that would fix the problem. I didnt check the Problem view. I am using the Eclipse Mars.2 Release(4.5.2) Build ID:20160218-0600. I did try the shortcut to remove the unused import. But the suggestion by @FredK actually fixed the issue.

Comment: Much clearer now. Given your Eclipse is two years behind, even if it was a bug at that time, probably not much use in filing a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Eclipse, select Project->Properties
then select Java Editor->Save Actions,
check "Additional actions", click on "Configure"
and then under "Unnecessary code"
be sure to select "Remove unused imports"

Comment: Manually removing the offending import should also take care of this, (though I'm personally a fan of letting the tool take care of it for me)

Comment: @jdkorv11
I did remove the imports manually, but it still showed the Warning incorrectly over the one the's being used. If you can refer to the 2nd part of screenshot, 
1. the import is being used. And it's not really the one that's unused.
2. And also notice that the warning is somehow also flowing down to the last line. 
3. When I hover over the warning, it shows an import that's not being used anymore.

Removing that warning now was the real problem, I had. Hope you get what I am saying.